# why some website(yahoo.com, alibaba.com, prothom-alo.com...) not loading in my ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, proxy

Even when I connect my internet showing this notification:
**Network service discovery disabled**
Your current network has a .local domain, which is not recommended and incompatible with the Avahi Network service discovery. The service has been disable.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` as root and find the line that contains `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=1`. If it doesn't exist, you can add it. Either way, you should edit the line to read `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0`. That should fix your problem.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1632952)